# Pointer to vector

Tags: c++, vector

I've got this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> *vecptr;
int veclen;

void getinput()
{
 string temp;
 for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
     cin>>temp;
     vecptr->push_back(temp);
    }
    veclen = vecptr->size();
}


int main()
{
 getinput();

    for(int i = 0; i < veclen; i++)
    {
     cout<<vecptr[i]<<endl;
    }

 return 0;
}
```

My compiler(G++) throw me some errors: test2.cpp:28:17: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << *(vecptr + ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)i) * 12u)))' ...

What's wrong? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The program is still not completely right. You have to initialize the vector pointer and then give it a size and the use it. A full working code could be,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> *vecptr = new vector<string>(10);
int veclen;

void getinput()
{
 string temp;
 for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
     cin>>temp;
     (*vecptr)[i] = temp;
    }
    veclen = (*vecptr).size();
}


int main()
{
 getinput();

    for(int i = 0; i < veclen; i++)
    {
     cout<<(*vecptr)[i]<<endl;
    }

 return 0;
}
```

Although I have mentioned the size as 10 you could make it a variant.

Answer (score 6):

You need to dereference `vecptr` here to get the underlying vector:

```
cout << (*vecptr)[i] << endl;
```

You will also need to initialize `vecptr`.